# REACT: Log all methods executed by an event, specifically touchstart and touchmove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, leaflet.draw, event-listener

As mentioned in the title, I am using React building an application with flux methodology in mind. How do I log all of the methods launched by a touchmove or touchstart event? Can't seem to find something like this on google...

Comment: My guess is the easiest way to do this would be to write your own redux middleware and make sure you're passing all your events directly through to your actions so when they are dispatched, the middleware can read the event type.  My suspicion is that this is pretty specific and there is no middleware currently out there that you can plug-and-play...

Answer (score 1):

I think the most value for least amount of code would come from creating your own middleware that looks for events in the action objects as they pass through the dispatch function. Here is some sample code below that works in react-create-app and can be easily modified to suit your purpose:

```
function createLogger(typeOfEvent) {
  return () => (next) => (action) => {
      let e;
      function isEvent(value) {
        return value.hasOwnProperty('bubbles')
      }
      Object.values(action).map(value => {
          if (isEvent(value)) {
            e = value;
          }
      })
      if (e.type === typeOfEvent) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      let returnValue = next(action)
      return returnValue
    }
}

const logger = createLogger('click')

export const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(logger));
```

Then make sure you dispatch all your actions with the appropriate event as a value somewhere:

```
<div className="App" onClick={(e) => store.dispatch({type: 'ACTION', e })}>
```